# MySQL binding two tables with different dimension

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables

Table A:

```js
X_Origin  | date    | uploads |    
--------------------------------
1         | 201501  | 10       |    
2         | 201501  | 50       | 
3         | 201502  | 70       | 
4         | 201503  | 150      | 
5         | 201503  | 120      |
```

Table B:

```css
X_Origin  | X_COUNTRY_CODE  | X_COUNTRY  |    
--------------------------------
1         | 34              | SPAIN      |    
2         | 21              | GERMANY    | 
4         | 34              | SPAIN      | 
5         | 21              | GERMANY    |
```

And I need to group by date and I can visualize the information of Spain (sum the uploads). I need something like this:

```css
X_Origin  | date    | uploads |  X_COUNTRY  |   
---------------------------------------
1         | 201501  | 10      |   Spain 
4         | 201503  | 150     |   Spain
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service

Comment: Show us your current attempt at writing the query for this, or go and find a SQL tutorial on the web, or you will have to wait for a `rep hound` to pass by

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
SELECT A.X_Origin, A.date, A.uploads, B.X_COUNTRY
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.A.X_Origin = B.A.X_Origin
WHERE B.X_COUNTRY = 'Spain'
AND A.X_dest = 'Spain'
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Now if I have another column on table A with the destination (X_dest), and I want a table with the uploads with origin spain and destination spain